# php array stored in session

Tags: php, session

**still no solution on this question**

So this is what I'm trying to do:

Have a product in a shopping cart with options. the options will be selectable through `<input type="checkbox/>` And the products are stored based on id's in sessions with php.

Right now I have the candies submitting as an array (like below) But I'm not sure how to add it to that specific product within the session.

My Input for the options is like this:

```
<?php foreach($options as $option): ?>
   <input type="checkbox" name="candies[]" value="<?php echo $option['candy_name']; ?>" /><?php echo $option['candy_name']; ?><br/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

My current code for adding the product to the session is like this:

```
...
case "add":
 $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++;
 header('location: ../../cart.html');
break;
...
```

I've also placed `$candies = $_GET["candies"];` above the above code to get the options.

How can I make it so the options array is stored in the session for each individual product?

In this image below, you can see what I'm talking about... I am wanting to display each selected option under the options column for the specific product.

[image]

Comment: What's in `$product_id`? Your PHP snippet doesn't say

Comment: It is simply: `$product_id = $_GET['id'];` So, the `product id` that is stored in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might not be the exact code you are looking for but this should serve as your guide to what you want to achieve.

Let's say you want to get the product options values from you database's productOptions.

```
$resultSet = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM productOptions");
```

Now we display the checkboxes to your form based on the result of the query.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultSet)){
     echo "<input type='checkbox' name='options[]' value='{$row['optionsID']}' />";
}
```

After displaying the check boxes to our form, we get the checked value from those check boxes that where selected.

```
if(isset($_POST['yourSubmitButtonName'])){
     $productSelected = array();
     if(!empty($_POST['options'])){
          foreach($_POST['options'] as $options){
               $optionsSelected[] = $options;
          }
     }
}
```

Now, set the array of options the the `$_SESSION` variable.

```
$_SESSION['yourProductID'] = $optionsSelected;
```

Then we display the options for a product this way

```
foreach($_SESSION['yourProductID'] as $productOptions){
     echo $productOptions;
}
```

Comment: Okay so i have the second block of code in one file (processes the submission) and then the last two blocks in a different file (displays the shopping cart) When I put it all together in one file (processing file) it works great. But when I break them apart like they have to be, I get this error on the shopping cart page: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/www/---/config/templates/shopping-cart.php on line 47` The session is started in this page and I can echo out `$product_id` but I can't with `$_SESSION[$product_id]`

Comment: Any ideas on what could be causing this problem?

Comment: @MitchEvans - I cannot figure out what's wrong with your code, I have tested the code above on my end and its working fine. I can also echo both variables. Be sure you initialize properly all the variables. Or you can post your code here and let's see what we can do to help you.

Comment: Please see my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246924/error-in-php-for-each-string?noredirect=1#comment32007970_21246924

Comment: I can't get all my code to post nicely. Would you be willing to screen share?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got the correct HTML structure but your code is disjointed. The simplest answer is to do something like this

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] = array('options' => $_POST['candies']);
```

Then you would do something like

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]['options'] as $opt) {
     echo $opt;
}
```

Comment: What happened to the `++` and When I replace `$_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++;` with your new code I get this error: `Fatal error: Unsupported operand types` I guess I'm not fully understanding.

Comment: See here: http://candy.the-green-panda.org/cart.html Exactly the errors I receive when implementing your code. Also the `$_POST['candies']` is already in an array.

Comment: Is `$_SESSION['cart']` already an array? I can't see why you would get that error.

Answer (score 0):

Code should look like this first html take checkbox

```
<form action="sample.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="candies[]" value="Candy1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="candies[]" value="Candy2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="candies[]" value="Candy3" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<form>
```

then session

```
<?php
session_start();
$result = array();
foreach ( $_POST['candies'] as $key=>$row ) :

    $result[$key] = $row[$key];
endforeach; 

$_SESSION['candies'] = $result;

print_r($_SESSION['candies']);

?>
```