# Error in PHP For each String

Tags: php, session

So let me first describe what I'm doing. I am making a shopping cart that allows options on items. The items along with it's respective chosen options are stored in sessions and display in a shopping cart for customer verification.

I have three sets of code to display to you:

- First off the code for making the check boxes for the options: (located in root/config/templates/product-details.php)

  ```
  <?php foreach($options as $option): ?>
     <input type="checkbox" name="candies[]" value="<?php echo $option['candy_name']; ?>" /><?php echo $option['candy_name']; ?><br/>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  ```
- Second the code for setting both the sessions for the item and options: (located in root/config/cart/cart.php

  ```
  $optionsSelected = array();
    if(!empty($_GET['candies'])){
     foreach($_GET['candies'] as $options){
       $optionsSelected[] = $options;
     }
    }

  case "add":
      $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++;
      $_SESSION[$product_id] = $optionsSelected;
      header('location: ../../cart.html');
  break;
  ```

*Note this line of code: `$_SESSION[$product_id] = $optionsSelected;`*

- And finally to display the options in the shopping cart: (located in root/config/templates/shopping-cart.php)

  ```
  <?php foreach($_SESSION[$product_id] as $options): ?>
      <?php echo $options; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  ```

When I have all that set up, I select the options I want and add a product to the shopping cart. I get this error on the shopping-cart.php page:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ...
```

But if I put the shopping-cart.php code inside the cart.php page and comment out the header(''); line Everything loads right and works wonderfully. So there is something wrong between the cart.php page and the shopping-cart.php page. But I can't figure out what it is. Any help, suggestions, thoughts, solutions would be wonderful and much much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

To help visually understand this question, here is a picture of the shopping-cart.php page.
[image]

**UPDATE**

I believe the problem is between the `root/config/cart/cart.php` page and the `root/config/templates/shopping-cart.php` page. Here is the full code for both.

- root/config/cart/cart.php code:

  ```
  <?php

  session_start();

  require '../config.php';

  $product_id = $_GET['id'];

  $action = $_GET['action'];

  $optionsSelected = array();
  if(!empty($_GET['candies'])){
      foreach($_GET['candies'] as $options){
          $optionsSelected[] = $options;
      }
  }

  function productExists($product_id) {

      require '../config.php';

      $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=$product_id");

      $stmt->execute(array($id, $name));

      $row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
  }

  if($product_id && $row_count < 0) {

      die("Error. Product Doesn't Exist");
  }

  switch($action) {

      case "add":
          $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++;
          $_SESSION[$product_id] = $optionsSelected;
          session_write_close();
          header('location: ../../cart.html');
      break;

      case "remove":
          $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]--;
          if($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] == 0) {
              unset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]);
              header('location: ../../cart.html');
          }
          header('location: ../../cart.html');

      break;

      case "empty": 
          unset($_SESSION['cart']);
      break;
  }

  ?>
  ```

Comment: Where does `$product_id` come from ?

Comment: I forgot to add that sorry. It comes from: `$product_id = $_GET['id'];` on the `root/config/cart/cart.php page`

Comment: You see that you redirect user to cart.html and there is no GET for id. Still you have `foreach($_SESSION[$product_id]`

Comment: Before you do your `foreach`, try doing this `var_dump($_SESSION);` and see what is listed in your session itself.

Comment: @Jompper -- $product_id is declared throughout, I can echo it out on every page within the foreach.

Comment: @Machavity -- I get `NULL` so there is a problem between the two pages.

Comment: I really wish I could figure this out...

Comment: @Jompper I see where your coming from, But the shopping-cart.php page is required in the cart.html page as following: `<?php require 'config/templates/shopping-cart.php'; ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much much trial and error, I finally got it to work exactly the way I wish...

I changed **root/config/cart/cart.php** to the following:

```
case "add":
   $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++;
   $_SESSION['options '.$product_id] = $optionsSelected;
   header('location: ../../cart.html');
break;
```

and then changed my for eache in the **root/config/templates/shopping-cart.php** to the following:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['options '.$product_id] > 0): ?>
   <?php foreach($_SESSION['options '.$product_id] as $option): ?>
      <p><?php echo $option; ?></p>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Honestly, I'm really not sure how it worked, but I managed to remove all errors and run the entire system exactly how I wish. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `session_start()` at the top of each page? It's required to utilize `$_SESSION` correctly.

-- Edit --

```
$_SESSION[$product_id] = $optionsSelected;
header('location: ../../cart.html');
```

Your session may actually not manage to "save" before the redirect, so you should try the following to rule that out:

```
$_SESSION[$product_id] = $optionsSelected;
session_write_close(); // :)
header('location: ../../cart.html');
```

Comment: Yes I am calling session_start(); at the top of each page. I am aware of that!

Comment: @MitchEvans Alright! I updated my response, could you give it a try?

Comment: I'm willing to try anything at this point! Give me a little bit to try.